# Lockable Surface in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I want a custom Control in WPF which have a appearance similar to HTML, we use for showing Images in the centre of the screen with the whole screen locked and only image is showing.

I dont want to show images, I want to show UserControls within this section.

Can someone give suggestions of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Window, put all your controls in a single Grid, with a Border control (that contains your image) as the last item in the Grid (which means it will display on top of the other items). Toggle its Visibility via binding or code. Adjust styles as required.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>

        <!-- window controls go here --->

        <Border Visibility="..." Background="#80000000"> <!-- EDITED -->

            <!-- overlaid image (and/or other controls) goes here --->
            <Image 
                Source="..." 
                Width="..."
                Height="..."
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        </Border>

    <Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I want a custom control. I have edited my question.

Comment: Well that's easy: replace the <Image /> in my example with whatever you need: <Grid>, <UserControl>, <my:CustomControl>, whatever!

Comment: I guess, this implementation will be for a particular window or usercontrol. I want to make a seperate control and use it at various places.

Comment: In that case I would use a WPF Popup control (or your own custom subclass of Popup), dynamically sized to fit exactly over the content you wish to block, be it a whole window, or just part of the window.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me a code snippet on how to proceed on this? Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution. I achieved it. But the problem is that the Control within the Border also appears with less Opacity. What should I do?

Comment: You are right - the opacity was being applied to the entire border and its content. I edited the code - see my answer again. I changed it so that the opacity is applied only to the color brush that fills the background (the hex color #80000000 is 50% black).

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Now I want to convert it to a control. Do check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595948/lockable-surface-control-in-wpf). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows applications this is generally achieved using a modal dialog, i.e. you create a normal WPF window and show it using [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).